# How can I get to click on a hypertext within the source code?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have started to write these command lines, but does seem to work correctly...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Row = Range("Name").Row And Target.Column = Range("Name").Column Then

        Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
        Dim downloadLink As HTMLAnchorElement
        Dim i As Long
        Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

        With ie
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "http://www.XXXXXXXXXX" & Range("Name").Value

            While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
            Wend
            Set HTMLdoc = .document
        End With

            Dim Elmt As IHTMLElement
            Dim Elm_Children As IHTMLElementCollection

            Elm = HTMLDocument.getElementById("tableList2")
            Elm_Children = Elm.Children
            ElmChildren.FirstChild.Click

        ie.Quit

    End If

End Sub
```

The source code looks like this :

[image]

The main idea is to open a search page and picup a search request listed in an Excel sheet, then click on the first hit and finaly scrap information in the new page: paste these informations in the same sheet but different lines.

Thanks a lot for the help :-)

Comment: `HTMLdoc` / `HTMLDocument` you only need one of these...  This is why you should always use `Option Explicit`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
HTMLDoc.querySelector("#tableList2 .lstw4 a[onclick]").Click
```

Or even

```
HTMLDoc.querySelector("#tableList2 [onclick*='openMainWindow']").Click
```

These use `#` id selector to get the table, `.` class selector in the first in descendant combinator to get the element with class `lstw4` within the table, both above use an attribute selector to target the `onclick` attribute. The first simply by going for first child `a` tag with `onclick` attribute and parent class `lstw4`, the second by `onclick` whose value contains `openMainWindow`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I am affraid not really understanding where I should replace the HTMLDoc...      Would you mind helping a bit more. Many thanks

Comment: Did you try the above? It would appear after the End With